# Using AutoLayout to fit a UILabel inside a UIView with a margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have a UILabel that I want to fit inside a UIView on iOS with a margin around the label.  I am adding the label pragmatically.  I want to add the constraints pragmatically too.

The problem is that the margin never works.   I have been researching this on google and on SO, but no luck so far.   When I add the constraint with this code, the margin never shows up, and the label fits entirely into the size of the parent view.  Again, I want a margin around the label.

Everything I read says that this should work.  I am using the following code to add the constraints, using the Visual Format Language.  Thanks!

```
self.textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.textLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10;
self.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

CGFloat edge = 25;
CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.frame, edge, edge);
rect = CGRectStandardize(rect);
self.textLabel.frame = rect; 

[self addSubview: self.textLabel];

stretchToSuperview(self.textLabel, 50.0, 1000);
```

Then, later:

```
void stretchToSuperview(UIView *view, CGFloat indent, NSUInteger priority)
{
    for (NSString *format in @[
                               @"H:|-indent-[view]-indent-|",
                               @"V:|-indent-[view]-indent-|"
                               ])
    {
        NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintsWithVisualFormat: format
                                options: 0
                                metrics: @{@"indent":@(indent)}
                                views: @{@"view": view}];
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in constraints)
        {
            constraint.priority = priority;
            [view.superview addConstraint: constraint];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks right to me. Are you sure the superview's frame is what you expect? Perhaps it's bigger than you expect and extends beyond the bounds of *its* superview and is clipped in such a way that the label coincides with the grandparent's edges.

Comment: Ken, thanks for responding.  I actually added a border to the layer of the textLabel so I can tell the border is right at the edge of the parent view.

Comment: Additionally, if I don't call stretchToSuperview(), I get the same results.  And, even if I don't set the frame, it still fills the space of it's parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This still should have worked, as posted, and I received feedback from several people.  To get what I wanted, I added a -layoutSubviews method to the parent view and added the following code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Important. This lets the Auto Layout engine do its job.
    [super layoutSubviews];


    // This is where we are setting the indentention from each edge
    //  of the textLabel from the parent .
    CGFloat edge = 20;
    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.textLabel.frame, edge, edge);
    self.textLabel.frame = rect;
}
```